# Scroll to selected cell in UITableView after selecting cell in UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set up a UISearchDisplayController such that after a cell is selected from the search results, the search display controller is dismissed and the table view scrolls to the selected cell.  Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
    {
         [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];

         // scroll to selected cell in table view here
    }
}
```

I know the method I need to use is:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

However, this method needs an index path from the main table view, not the search results table view.  How can I get this index path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your datasource look like? Perhaps you can query the datasource based on what was selected in the search results to get the cell's index.

Sounds like a strange user interaction not knowing what you're doing though. Normally searching and then selecting will take you to that record's details or select it as an option or something.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I was hoping for some kind of built in method to deal with the situation, but querying the datasource works.  The goal of the interaction was to be able to search through a contact list, mark a contact as selected, then go back to the table view with that selected contact visible in the table view.